# Are Lay's potato chips halal?

Tags: halal-haram, food

I heard rumors. Can you confirm if [Lay's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lay%27s) are halal or haram?

Comment: See also: [Are Pringles halal or haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17188/17163)

Answer (score 3):

This might depend on your location.

Lays may contain the ingredient [E631](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disodium_inosinate). This can be manufactured from e.g:

- animals, including pigs
- yeast from brewing alcohol
- fish
- bacterial fermentation of sugars and plant matter

The first two sources are ***haram*** and the last two are ***halal***. The answer to your question depends on whether or not you can verify the origin of the ingredients, and whether or not you trust the claim made on it.

See: http://www.food-info.net/uk/e/e631-lays.pdf

Comment: @VasimVanzara Fish is halal, see [Quran 5:96](https://quran.com/5/96) and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/which-foods-from-the-sea-are-halal/

Comment: Lays is not haram, but it can become haram